# How can I get output of 2 files with no-duplicates of lines [from any file]?

Tags: bash

Given two files (so that at any file can be duplicates) in the following format:

***file1*** (file that contains only numbers) **for example:**

> 10
>   40
>   20
>   10
>   10

***file2*** (file that contains only numbers) **for example:**

> 30
>   40
>   10
>   30
>   0

How can I prints the contents of the files, so that, from any file, we will remove the duplications.

For example, the output according to the 2 file above, need to be:

> **10**
>   **40**
>   **20**
>   30
>   40
>   10
>   0

Note: in the output, we can get duplications (at most, will be 2 number that appears two times) , but, from any file, we will take the content without duplications !

**How can I do it with `sort , uniq , cat` using only one command?**

Namely, something like that: `cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq` (but, of course, this command not good - it's not solve the problem, it's only for explain what I mean while I say "using only one command").

I will be happy to listen your ideas how do it :)

Comment: Using only `sort, uniq, cat` will give you a hard time trying to preserve the order.

Comment: @PesaThe We don't must preserve the order (I don't said that the output need to preserve the order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, this `awk` should do it while preserving the order:

```
awk 'FNR==1{delete a}!a[$0]++' file1 file2
```

If you don't need to preserve the order, it can be as simple as:

```
sort -u file1; sort -u file2
```

If you don't want to use a list (`;`), something like this is also an option:

```
cat <(sort -u file1) <(sort -u file2)
```

Comment: What with `sort -u file1 file2` ? It's will do it about any file , or about the two files?

Comment: See my edition to the commant. I asked "what with.." and not "what is.."

Comment: It would sort the union. That's why you need `sort` twice, to sort both files independently, as far as I know.